# Making menu item in TYPO3 Bootstrap non-clickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, typo3, typoscript

I am using TYPO3 8.7.9 with the Bootstrap Extension 9.1.0 (from Benjamin Kott).

For the pages I am using the bootstrap root and extension templates.

I have a simple tree of pages like

```
root
    sub1           <-- no content, want it to be non-clickable
        subsub1
        subsub2
    sub2
    sub3
    sub4           <-- no content, want it to be non-clickable
        subsub3
        subsub4
    sub5
```

The menu is built automatically from the tree (responsive, may collapse to hamburger icon).

I would like to make menu entries non-clickable - in the example above sub1 and sub4. (The pages sub1 and sub4 are empty.)

Also in the breadcrump the pages sub1 and sub4 should not be clickable.

Did I miss a configuration option? Is there a simple way with some TypoScript? And where do I have to place it? root/ext template setup, page TSConfig?

Thanks for looking into it,

Zweikeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to change the Boostrap `Navigation` template file.

You can find this file below paths. Here you can change the menu layout and menu functionality.

```
typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Navigation/
```

Comment: I'm working on it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. At first: To make the changes under fileadmin
1) copied over the 5 html files from Navigation to fileadmin/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Navigation, keeping the folder structure
2) changed partialRootPath - for completeness all 3 - in the constant editor of the root page, BOOTSTRAP PACKAGE: ADVANCED, pointing to fileadmin instead of EXT:
(The path to EXT: is automatically kept as a 'fallback', can be seen in the TypoScript Object Browser. Since TYPO3 6.2 it is possible to just 'override' individual files.)

Comment: Yes you can override Boostrap template file using Typoscript

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for your help. I just try to give some hints to others: Main.html and Breadcrumb.html need to be changed. <f:debug> helps a lot. Link could always be suppressed based on children (easy in Main, more elaborate in Breadcrumb). Based on an own BE setting gets tricky since a new variable mus be handed over. I don't use shortcut pages in my design. So I chose to flag link suppression by setting the page type to shortcut, evaluating doktype in Main and Breadcrumb. Set class="active" for suppressed links in Breadcrumb to get correct coloring without the need to change the CSS.